# See if one person is before another in the alphabet, ruby, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm doing an app for a membership database.

Each person may have a partner.  When it comes to displaying the list, I only want to have one row for each family, so at the moment I'm comparing first names and not displaying the row if the person's name is second.  Like this

```
person.first_name != [person.first_name, person.partner.first_name].sort[0]
```

This means each family only gets displayed once, not twice - once for each partner.

And I'm doing this in the view.

There must be a better way of doing this, and it'd be really great if I could do it at the database level.  I'm using postgresql if that makes a difference.

Edit

---

Sorry if it was unclear.

Say Person 1 has the first_name "Edward" and Person 2 has the first_name "Fay".  Edward and Fay are married.

I only want to show them once in my list - I want a row to look like this

```
Surname     First name    Address    etc
Mysurname   Edward        ....
            Fay
```

I don't want to display it again with Fay first because I've got both Fay and Edward in list of people, so I use the ruby in the first part of the question to check if I should display the row - it compares their first names and only does the row if the person has a fist name that's before his/her partner's first name.

Here's the relevant part of my person model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :relationship_link,  :foreign_key => :person_id, :dependent => :destroy, :include => :partner
  has_one :partner, :through => :relationship_link, :source => :person_b, :class_name => "Person"
```

I hope that's clearer

Comment: What does it mean by "the person's name is second"? And, by "once for each partner", did you mean "once for each pair/couple"?

Comment: Membership database, person, partner and family. It is difficult to understand your problem with these. It would be more clear, if you could paste the real relationships on your model.

Comment: What is the outcome you are trying to achieve? An example would be useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `DISTINCT ON` or `GROUP BY`. In postgres you need to be careful to group by everything that you are selecting. If you only need to get the last names you can `select("DISTINCT ON(last_name) last_name").pluck("last_name")`. You will only get an array of last names though.

Maybe you can get records if you order by every other fields in your table, like this:

```
select("DISTINCT ON(people.last_name) people.*").order("people.last_name ASC, people.first_name ASC, people.field2 DESC, people.field3 ASC...")
```

You need to order by **every** attribute so the result is not ambigious.

Comment: But what if people have the same surname and aren't partners?

Comment: Add relationship_link_id to DISTINCT ON then or use GROUP BY in a similar way. DISTINCT ON and GROUP BY work similarly.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, i would create a data structure (a Hash) to store people instances given a specific surname. Something like this:

```
def build_surnames_hash(people_array)
  surnames_hash = {}
  people_array.each do |person|
    last_name = person.last_name
    surnames_hash[last_name] ||= []
    surnames_hash[last_name] << person
  end
  surnames_hash
end
```

That way, you can iterate over the hash and display people using their surnames stored as hash's keys:

```
surnames_hash = build_surnames_hash(Person.all)

surnames_hash.each do |surname, person_instances_array|
  # display the surname once
  # iterate over person_instances_array displaying their properties
end
```

Comment: But what if people have the same surname and aren't partners?

Comment: Well, somehow their surnames will distinguish from each other, right? Anyway, you will never know unless they have differences...